# Android ormlite config getters relationship depth

Tags: android, ormlite, depth

Hy,

I'm new in android app developing. I'm working on a project, and have the following problem:
When I search for an object in the database, and want to access it's relationship objects, after a few dept I get back null, not the needed object. Forexample:

```
order.getCustomer().getAddress().getCity() // returns null, not the City name
Customer customer = dao.getOnById(order.getCustomer(), Customer.class); // get the Customer from DB, by it's id
customer().getAddress().getCity() // returns correct value - City name, not null
```

I want to access attributes trough foreign key constraints. Have a CustomerEntiy class, which has a DatabaseField(foreign = true) attribute: private OrderEntity orders; OrderEntity has an AddressEntity type databaseField. And AddressEntity got a String type city attribute. I want to access this attribute. If i try to access it trough orderEntity, i always get back null (sample first line), but if i search back the CustomerEntity (select it with id from database),I can access the city attribute, and it returns with the correct value. Can I increase this foreign key access depth? I get this problem after 5th dept.

I'm using ormlite, android 7.1

Thank You for your answer,
Chris

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you add more details?  What do you mean by depth?  Can you show the entity?

Comment: I want to access attributes trough foreign key constraints.I extend my previous example:
Have a CustomerEntiy class, which has a DatabaseField(foreign = true) attribute: private OrderEntity orders; OrderEntity has an AddressEntity type databaseField. And AddressEntity got a String type city attribute.
I want to access this attribute. If i want to access it trough orderEntity, i always get back null (order.getCustomer().getAddress().getCity() // returns null), but if i get back the CustomerEntity (select it with id),I can access the city attribute.Can I increase this fireign key access depth?

Comment: Sorry, please edit your answer to improve it and answer my questions.  Thanks.